# Como pegar valor retornado de Get utilizando Volley em android

Tags: java, android, rest, volley

No caso eu quero saber como pegar somente o valor do GET do link ".../possui_cadastro" para entrar no If ou no Else.

```
public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {
private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://192.168.30.12:5000/possui_cadastro";
private Map<String, String> params;

public LoginRequest(Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Method.GET, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // display response
                    if (response.toString() == "1") {


                        Context mContext = null;

                        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, GpsActivity.class)
                                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    }

                    else {

                        Context mContext = null;

                        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, RegisterActivity.class)
                                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);

                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("Error.Response", String.valueOf(error));
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método get está certo. O if (response.toString() == "1") não se torna verdadeiro pois na variável existe um espaço antes do número 1, então é só aplicar na variável a função trim() que remove espaços em branco: if (response.toString().trim() == "1")